# Can multiple background images alternate when repeated?

Tags: css, background, background-repeat, background-image

I am trying to alternately tile multiple backgrounds images using CSS. Here is the essence of what I am trying, with two small square images `X` and `O`:

```
background-image: url(images/X.png), url(images/O.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
```

This is the desired effect (spacing added for clarity):

```
XXX OOO XXX OOO XXX OOO
XXX OOO XXX OOO XXX OOO
```

But this is the actual effect:

```
XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
```

The foremost background layer, `X`, seems to be repeated adjacent to itself, which is causing the secondary background layer, `Y` to be drawn behind and thus hidden.

Can multiple background images be alternately tiled? I would prefer not to combine the images as a single image. I also don't know how wide the element will be, so faking the repeat by specifying the same image more than once is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is make both the images twice as wide and on either left or right side a transparent image. Haven't tried it, but should work and maybe not the beautiful solution you were looking for?

Also, not sure why you don't want to repeat 1 combined image of XXX 000?

Comment: I would rather not modify the images in any way. They are effectively a stand-in, and may be replaced with other backgrounds, such as gradients.

Comment: Okay, I've done a bit of digging around and I'm afraid I don't see an easy solution to your problem using one element. I think you're best off creating a (javascript) grid and have a background image for each element.

Comment: I ended up doing it in JavaScript, though I think this will eventually be possible using only CSS. It could be done with a dummy element that effectively combines the images as its background, then using the (now mostly unsupported) element(#dummy) function as the background with a repeat. Seems like there should be a simpler solution, though, probably an opportunity for a `background-padding` property or similar.

Comment: Great. If you want to propose/discuss anything in Style/CSS, I think this is the mailinglist for it: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/.  More general information about participating: http://www.w3.org/participate/

Comment: Been subscribed to the mailing list for a while. :-)